# How can I write a script that uses the search feature for NCBI and downloads all the results as a FASTA file?

Tags: python

I need to write a script that uses the search function on NCBI (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/), narrows the results down to the Nucleotide database and downloads the results of the search as a Fasta file. What would such a code look like?

Answer (score 1):

This is typically called screen-scraping. Relevant libraries are;

- [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) for doing HTTP calls
- [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing HTML